# How to save SQL stored procedures to .sql files via batch

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, export

I woud like to save my MS SQL Server 2005 stored procedures to .sql files automatically (would prefer a tool which I can call via .bat) so I don't have to click each single sproc manually and save it.

I have already found SMOscript from devio IT, but it gathers all tables and sproc which takes some time. Is there any similar tool where I can define which sproc(s) to export? Also I'm missing the `USE <DB>` clause which SMOScript doesn't add to exported file in contrast to the manuall export as script sproc for `CREATE`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create batch file with script (sorry about formatting, but it's really should be inline to execute batch):

```
osql -U %1 -P %2 -S %3 -d %4 -h-1 -Q "SELECT ROUTINE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Routines WHERE ROUTINE_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE'" -n -o "sp_list.txt"
for /f %%a in (sp_list.txt) do osql -U %1 -P %2 -S %3 -d %4 -h-1 -Q "SELECT ROUTINE_DEFINITION FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Routines WHERE ROUTINE_NAME = '%%a'" -n -o "%%a.sql"
```

Name it "run.bat". Now, to execute batch use params:
run.bat [username] [password] [servername] [database]
on example:
run.bat sa pwd111 localhost\SQLEXPRESS master
first all stored procedure names will be stored in file sp_list.txt, then one by one  in separate script files. The only issue - last line of each script with result count - I'm workin' on it :)

**edited**: bug in query fixed

**Removing "Rows affected" line**
Ok, now we need to create one more batch:

```
type %1 | findstr /V /i %2  > xxxtmpfile 
copy xxxtmpfile %1 /y /v
del xxxtmpfile
```

Name it "line_del.bat". See, the first param is file to process, 2nd - string to search lines for removing. Now modify the main batch (again, sorry about formatting):

```
osql -U %1 -P %2 -S %3 -d %4 -h-1 -Q "SELECT ROUTINE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Routines WHERE ROUTINE_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE'" -n -o "sp_list.txt"
call line_del sp_list.txt "rows affected"
call line_del sp_list.txt "row affected"
for /f %%a in (sp_list.txt) do osql -U %1 -P %2 -S %3 -d %4 -h-1 -Q "SELECT ROUTINE_DEFINITION FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Routines WHERE ROUTINE_NAME = '%%a'" -n -o "%%a.sql" 
for /f %%a in (sp_list.txt) do call line_del %%a.sql "rows affected"
for /f %%a in (sp_list.txt) do call line_del %%a.sql "row affected"
```

See related articles:
[Simple programming commands in a batch environment](http://www.aumha.org/a/batches.php)
[osql Utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214012(SQL.80).aspx)
[MSSQL: How do you script Stored Procedure creation with code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513158/mssql-how-do-you-script-stored-procedure-creation-with-code)
[Delete certain lines in a txt file via a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418916/delete-certain-lines-in-a-txt-file-via-a-batch-file)

:) you may notice, last two are from SO!

Comment: Wouldn't this break for large procs? When I run: SELECT ROUTINE_NAME , max(len(ROUTINE_DEFINITION)) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Routines 
group by ROUTINE_NAME 
order by 2 desc; I get a lot of procs that are 4000 characters. Pretty sure you need to pull out of sys.comments to get the right data.

Comment: Oops, that should be syscomments in the comment above.

Answer (score 3):

There is an alternative in SQL Server Management Studio, scripting the database...

Expand the Object Explorer view to find the database, right click and select "Tasks : Generate Scripts"

From there you can script all object, just stored preocedures, of anything in between.  There are quite a few options on one page, though the main one I change is:
- "Include IF NOT EXISTS"

By making that option "FALSE" then you just get a whole list of CREATE statements.

You can then choose to script the objects to a new query window, or a file.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the SET NOCOUNT ON did indeed eliminate the need for the line_del.bat, but replacing syscomments with sys.sql_modules resulted in each stored procedure being truncated to 258 characters. So for the best results the code I used was:

```
sqlcmd -E -S SERVER-d DB -h-1 -Q "SET NOCOUNT ON SELECT ROUTINE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Routines WHERE ROUTINE_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE'" -o "sp_list.txt"
for /f %%a in (sp_list.txt) do sqlcmd -E -S SERVER-d DB -h-1 -Q "SET NOCOUNT ON SELECT text from dbo.syscomments WHERE id = OBJECT_ID('%%a')" -o "%%a.sql"
```

Which worked, and did not need the use of the line_del.bat. What I didnt get when I did the manual export using the SSMS wizard (Tasks/Generate Scripts/Stored Procedures/Select All) was the:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
```

at the beginning of each .sql, and the trailing GO command also. Not incredibly important but something to note. Thanks to Max Gontar, Seansilver and Lee for your contributions! I can now automate the backup of the stored procedures in the database, and apply version control.

Answer (score 0):

I've used sqlcmd and -E instead of user, pass. This works fine so far, just stored procedures longer than 4000 chars will have a line break

```
sqlcmd -E -S SERVER -d DB -h-1 -Q "SELECT ROUTINE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Routines WHERE ROUTINE_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE'" -o "sp_list.txt"
call line_del sp_list.txt "rows affected"
call line_del sp_list.txt "row affected"
for /f %%a in (sp_list.txt) do sqlcmd -E -S SERVER -d DB -h-1 -Q "SELECT text from dbo.syscomments WHERE id = OBJECT_ID('%%a')" -o "%%a.sql"
for /f %%a in (sp_list.txt) do call line_del %%a.sql "rows affected"
for /f %%a in (sp_list.txt) do call line_del %%a.sql "row affected"
```

best regards
sean

Answer (score 0):

I added SET NOCOUNT ON to eliminate the need for line_del.bat. Also replaced syscomments with sys.sql_modules (SQL 2005). I could also have used the OBJECT_DEFINITION function but it was slower than sys.sql_modules.

```
sqlcmd -E -S SERVER -d DB -h-1 -Q "SET NOCOUNT ON SELECT ROUTINE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Routines WHERE ROUTINE_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE'" -o "sp_list.txt" for /f %%a in (sp_list.txt) do sqlcmd -E -S SERVER -d DB -h-1 -Q "SET NOCOUNT ON SELECT definition from sys.sql_modules WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('%%a')" -o "%%a.sql"
```

Comment: Not a standalone answer, should be a comment on the answer that you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all above for help and leaving this here for other sqlcmd noobs like myself to find.  Works on sql server 2005.   objectName being a procedure, view etc name.

```
:reset

-- :setvar ObjectName "objectName"  -- works
:setvar ObjectName objectName  -- works too
declare @sql varchar(max);
set @sql = 'select text from dbo.syscomments where id = object_id(upper("' + '$(ObjectName)' + '"))';
-- exec sp_helptext $(ObjectName)  -- quick n easy but gets chopped to 256 width
/*   4000 byte limit
set @sql = 
   'select view_definition 
    from information_schema.views 
    where upper(table_name) = upper("' + '$(ObjectName)' + '")';
*/
:out $(ObjectName).sql

exec(@sql)
go

:out stdout
```